# XML File Update using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I would like to update the Date attribute using PowerShell. `SelectNodes` methods is not working because of how the XML (3rd party built, can't update the schema) is formatted. Is there a way I could update the Date field using PowerShell XML feature?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<JOBS>
  <ScheduleDetails Environment="Env1" Type="Prod" Recursive="Y" Date="2021-10-06 20:00" Finished="N" Running="N" Interval="7" />
  <ScheduleDetails Environment="Env2" Type="Prod" Recursive="Y" Date="2021-10-06 20:10" Finished="N" Running="N" Interval="7" />
  <ScheduleDetails Environment="Env3" Type="Prod" Recursive="Y" Date="2021-10-06 20:20" Finished="N" Running="N" Interval="7" />
</JOBS>
```

Comment: You say `SelectNodes()` doesn't work, can you show us the code you tried that failed? And let us know which errors (if any) it resulted in

Comment: Thanks!  I was using '```$xmlProperty = $config.SelectNodes("/JOBS/ScheduleDetails/Date")``` instead of
```$xmlProperty = $config.SelectNodes("/JOBS/ScheduleDetails")```

Comment: Date is not a node name, you'll want something like `$config.SelectNodes('//ScheduleDetails') |ForEach-Object { $_.Date = "New Date Value" }` instead